# Equivalent of "in" keyword or subquery in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series object (let's call this `MySeries`) which contains a list of integers.

I also have a separate dataframe (say `MyDataFrame`), which includes a column/field called `MyField`.

I want to select all records from `MyDataFrame` where the value in `MyField` is in `MySeries`

The equivalent SQL would be:

```
Select * from MyDataFrame 
where MyField in 
    (select * from MySeries)
```

Could anyone suggest the best way to do this?

Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can use [isin()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) function:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5], 'B':list('ABCDE')})
>>> f = pd.Series([1,2])
>>> df[df['A'].isin(f)]
   A  B
0  1  A
1  2  B
```

so, first you get fiter Series:

```
>>> df['A'].isin(f)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
```

And then use it to filter your DataFrame